# Why do different compilers produce different sized files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

I recently installed MinGW on Windows 10 with the packages for C and C++. The other day, I decided to compile some C++ using Visual Studio 1029's compiler and g++ to see if there was a difference. There was a major difference in that the file produced by g++ is over four times larger than the file produced by VS19.

Here's what I did: I first opened Visual Studio and created a Visual C++ Console Application named `Test1`. I then placed the following code in main.cpp:

```cpp
// Test1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Then I went to the build menu, configured VS19 to release mode, and built the project. Then I opened the solution folder, navigated to the `Release` folder and copied the .exe file. I then created a folder elsewhere, named `sizes` (any name should work), and pasted the .exe file there, under the name `VS.exe`. I then went back to the solution folder for Visual Studio, navigated to the `Test1` directory, copied the `Test1.cpp` file, and pasted it in my `sizes` folder as `main.cpp`. I then opened PowerShell in the `sizes` folder and ran the following commands:

```
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes> g++ -o mingwgpp.exe main.cpp
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes> gci

    Directory: C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/12/2020     15:01                .vs
-a----        5/12/2020     14:13            173 main.cpp
-a----        5/12/2020     15:01          47192 mingwgpp.exe
-a----        5/12/2020     14:14          10752 vs.exe
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes> ./vs.exe
Hello World!
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes> ./mingwgpp.exe
Hello World!
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\Documents\C_C++\Sizes>
```

Interestingly, even though they are both built from the same source code, the executable built through Visual Studio is far more compact. Why is this?

Comment: Yes I would fully expect that they should produce different sized files almost every time unless the code is trivial. But even then they may have different runtimes, different standard library implementations and initialization code.

Comment: For Visual Studio, check the type of runtime library you are using.  If it's the DLL version of the runtime, for example, **Multithreaded DLL**, then expect the VS version to be smaller.  If you then change it to **Multithreaded**, and rebuild, then recheck the sizes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do I do this?

Comment: It's in your project settings in Visual Studio.  **Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library**

Comment: @AwesomeCronk The real test is to add up the sizes of all the runtime files you need to run a release version of the application on a clean machine (a computer that does not have MingW or Visual Studio installed).  That is a better gauge of the footprint of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume each compiler as a different software to create machine-runnable code from Files containing code which is programmed according to a specific standard, e.g. C++.
Each of these compilers have their specific skills/features. A good compiler optimizes the code. This is also the reason why code compiled in debug mode is mostly much slower than the release compiled code.

To have a look on it, try https://godbolt.org/ There you can choose the compiler and can analyse the output.